# SSRS: How to use same dimension & hierarchy for 2 parameters

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, hierarchy, dimension

So, I'm stuck on how to resolve this issue.

I would like to use the same Dimension & Hierarchy two times.

The dimension and Hierachy is already used one time to exclude a column value.

Now I would like to add a parameter to the same hierachy/dimension (with acfource the earlier rule applied)

And I can't get my head around to solve this.

Comment: You are excluding a columns from a hierarchy and you want to use that column to filter?

Comment: Lets say I have a column with the values:
1,2,3,4

And I want to exclude data that contains value 4 in that column
So how its been done earlier is that hierarchy not equal 4

And then I want another parameter on that same hierarchy that says
equal 1,23

And be able to choose 1,2,3 when i want to render my report and i want to be sure that 4 is equaled out.

Could I then just say equal 1,2,3 and make a parameter and be sure that data with 4 is not read.

or do i need to add some dynamic filter or something else?

Comment: Post the mdx you have so far, explain what value you want to exclude and populate the parameter .

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, then the solution is fairly simple. For each parameter that requires a dropdown list you need a different dataset in your report. For the first parameter (@p1), set available values and labels based on the result of a query.

In the dataset for the second parameter (@p2) which should have a filtered dropdown, have a second dataset that will be used to set the available values and labels of the second parameter. In this dataset, you want to reference the value of @p1 somewhere in your query. Upon opening, the report will generate the results of the first dataset to populate the first parameter's dropdown list. Once a value has been selected for @p1, the report will generate the second dataset to populate the options for the @p2 dropdown list. In this way, you can dynamically filter the options available to the dropdown list for the second parameter.